# how is the file /proc/net/dev filled?

Tags: wifi, linux-kernel

So, I'm writing a kernel module that needs stats about local network interfaces and I came up with the following code ... everything works fine except for the part where I try to read wireless device stats ... apparently the `wireless_handler` struct is not filled because the `CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT` is not set ... my question? Where does `ifconfig` get its' wireless stats from?

```
struct net_device *dev;
struct net_device_stats *stats;             
struct iw_statistics *wi_stats;
dev = first_net_device(&init_net);
while (dev)
{
    if (strncmp(dev->name , "wlan",4)==0 && (dev->flags & IFF_UP) == 1)
            {

        #ifndef CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT
        wi_stats = dev -> wireless_handlers -> get_wireless_stats(dev);
        #endif      
        }
        else if (strncmp(dev->name , "eth",3)==0 || strncmp(dev->name , "lo",2)==0) 
            {
        stats = dev->netdev_ops->ndo_get_stats(dev);
        printk(KERN_INFO "recive packets: [%li]\ntransmitted packets: [%li]\nrecive errors: [%li]\ntransmission errors: [%li]\nnumber of collisions: [%li]", 
                stats->rx_packets , stats->tx_packets ,stats->rx_errors , stats->tx_errors, stats->collisions);
            }

    dev = next_net_device(dev);
}//end while
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `strace`, you can see `iwconfig` doing something like this:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
ioctl(3, SIOCGIWNAME, 0xbfb02c7c)       = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIWNWID, 0xbfb02c7c)       = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
ioctl(3, SIOCGIWFREQ, 0xbfb02c7c)       = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
ioctl(3, SIOCGIWENCODE, 0xbfb02c7c)     = 0
```

And a dozen or so other `ioctl`s follow. Chase down those `ioctl`s in the kernel and you'll find where the data is.

Comment: is there a way to use `ioctl` from a kernel module? is there another way to get values such as `SIOCGIWNAME` other than using ioctl ?

Comment: `ioctl`s cross the user/kernel boundary. If there's no kernel space API to get the information, you may have to get creative (write a userspace daemon, for instance). Take this with a pinch of salt, please. I've never had to do something like this with the kernel. Most of my kernel coding has been straightforward drivers, minor patches etc.

Comment: away from that, any idea how/who writes on the file `/proc/net/dev` or `/proc/net/wireless`?

Comment: A `grep` for `proc` inside `net/wireless` suggests `net/wireless/wext.c` (that's where `/proc/net/wireless` is ‘created’). You should probably read through the code in `net/wireless`, it seems to do what you need.

Comment: this `net/wireless/wext.c` file does not exist in the kernel I'm using (2.6.35)

Comment: 2.6.32 apparently has `wext.c`. On 2.6.38 (and probably 2.6.35), it's been split up into various files. You want `wext-proc.c`. `grep` is your friend.

Comment: this is kinda embarrassing, but how are you using grep to know who's made changes to a file ?

Comment: I'm not. ‘Files’ under `/proc` are created by C code whenever they're read, so they don't exist as such. I don't look for ‘who/what’ writes the file, I look for signs of the various `proc_*` functions (e.g. `grep proc *.c`). In this case, with `wext-proc.c` it's kinda easy to guess where the files are generated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The condition for the pre-processor says  IF NOT DEFINED CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT

Which means your code is ONLY included when there is NOT wireless card support... isn't this backwards?

```
    #ifndef CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
    #ifdef CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT
```

Comment: Um, sorry about that, that was a typo ... but anyway even when using `#ifdef CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT` still the `wireless_handlers` is still null

again, my question is Where does ifconfig get its' wireless stats from?

Comment: Your best source of that information would be "Use The Source, Luke".   Download the source code of ifconfig/iwconfig and see how it does it.  No shame there.  I've learned quite a bit from looking at other code.   Be careful, you said ifconfig, where I imagine you meant iwconfig.

Comment: I can see that iwconfig uses ioctl calls .. is this possible to perform from kernel space in a kernel module?

Comment: Certainly, but be sure to the SYSCALL for ioctl (32bit=#54, 64bit=#16) rather than the libc version, you don't want to call OUT of the kernel.  Otherwise, everything's the same for usage.  32bit & 64bit syscall numbers are DIFFERENT, be sure to use the symbol for the call# to make things easier... BOTH 54 & 16 are referred to by SYS_ioctl (and __NR_ioctl in a lower definition)  Have a look at /usr/include/syscall.h (which will include another... and another... keep digging, it's there, deep in bits/syscall.h and asm/unistd_(32|64).h)

Comment: are you suggesting something like the example written here http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x892.html ?

Comment: Yes.  Considering that example is in the "Kernel Module Programming Guide" ... I'd say yes.